# Perl Catalyst: How to re-use applications

Tags: perl, catalyst

I did implement a Catalyst authentication application (captchas, password reminders, access logs, etc...).
How am I supposed to re-use it in different Catalyst applications? I.e.: 
Or - more generally - how am I supposed to let two applications talk each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can abstract common components in your local catalystX namespace and extend your controllers and models from that namespace .

Comment: +v +v +v ;-) Can you please be a little more "verbose"?

Answer (score 2):

You're basically asking : `I have build two airplanes, how do I let them talk to each other?`

Maybe see Catalyst::Plugin::Authentication (and module that use it) and make one yourself,
or something else entirely,  like a radio